# Multibib with TeXworks: how to parse second .aux file?

Tags: compiling, subdividing, texworks, multibib

I need to use the multibib package to create a double bibliography document.

I am currently working with TeXworks 0.4.3 (on Windows 7), but I cannot make the double bibliographies system work.

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
%Secondary bibliography
\newcites{sec}{Secondary contributions}

Text with \citet{primauthor} and \citetsec{secauthor}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{tbib}
\bibliographystylesec{plainnat}
\bibliographysec{tbib}

\end{document}
```

TeXworks correctly produces the "sec.aux" file... But I don't know how to make it process this file! The multibib package says I should put a for cycle

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.aux ; do
bibtex ‘basename $file .aux‘
done
```

but I have no idea where to put it... :D

I have tried to make the following test (Thesis is the name of the base tex file):

[image: The try I have made]

with no sensible results... any suggestion would be appreciated...

Comment: Can you save the shell script to a file, make it executable, and then invoke this file from the TeXworks window you display?

Comment: i use texmaker but had the same problem, i added "bibtex sec.aux" to my own build-script and it works. "bibtex sec" did not create the bbl file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The script provided in the `multibib` documentation is Unix-based, so we will have troubles running it in Windows. In the script, there's also another command running inside single quotes - `basename $file .aux` - which returns the full path for `$file` (which is the current element in the `for` loop).

The solution is to manually run these commands in the following order:

```
pdflatex mydoc
bibtex mydoc
bibtex sec
pdflatex mydoc
pdflatex mydoc
```

As Mico suggested in the comments, you can also create a Windows-equivalent batch file. It's been a while since my last Windows batch file, but I'm almost sure we can use this one:

```
@echo off
FOR %%A IN (*.aux) DO bibtex %%A
```

Save it as `myscript.bat`. It will run `bibtex` on all `.aux` files in the current directory. Now, I think TeXworks might not run the batch file in the current directory, so we need to change things a little:

```
@echo off
FOR %%A IN (*.aux) DO bibtex %1\%%A
```

and then make TeXworks call `myscript.bat` with `$directory` as argument (note that `$directory` is a TeXworks variable which expands to the absolute path to the directory containing your root document).

Another suggestion (and sorry for tooting my own horn here) is to use [`arara`](https://github.com/cereda/arara) to automate your document compilation. The header would be:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ mydoc, sec ] }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
...
```

The secret here is the second line containing the `bibtex` directive. `arara` will run `bibtex` on `mydoc` (your document name), and also on `sec`.

<sub>Sorry for not providing screenshots and more info, I'm away from my Windows machine right now.</sub>

Comment: wow thanks for the comprehensive answer, that worked sweetly! I gave a look at arara and it is very interesting (I do love palindrome myself), but I'm not sure I can understand how to make it work at its full potentiality in a reasonable time

Comment: @scannerdarkly Yay, I'm glad it worked! `:)` By the way, don't worry about `arara`, it really takes some time to grasp the concepts - it might not be intuitive in the first couple of tries. `:P`

Comment: I am TOTALLY confused...how a commented command can run in latex editor?