# Publications not showing up using moderncv

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, multibib

I'm new to LaTeX, so I might be making a very simple mistake, but I can't seem to get my publications to show up on my CV. I'm using the `moderncv` and `multibib` packages and MiKTeX. Here's a simplifi:

The references are in a file called `publication.bib`:

```
@article{article1,
  title={Article 1},
  author={Doe, J.},
  year={2012},
  journal={Journal}
}
@book{book1,
  title={Book 1},
  author={Doe, J.},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
```

And the `CV.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}  
\moderncvstyle{banking}                        
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{somewhere}{}    

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{article,book}{{Articles},{Books}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
\section{Publications}
\nocitebook{book1}
\bibliographystylebook{plain}
\bibliographybook{publication.bib} 

\nocitearticle{article1}
\bibliographystylearticle{apacite}
\bibliographyarticle{publication.bib}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

When I typeset it, the header, etc. all come out right, but the Publications section is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am using the `Typeset` command in MikTeX/TeXworks with pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX, which I assume runs bibtex, but I am not sure. I looked through the log and found this, which seems relevant, but I don't know how to fix: `LaTeX Warning: Citation 'book1' undefined on input line 20.` ... `No file book.bbl.` ... `LaTeX Warning: Citation 'article1' undefined on input line 24.`...`No file article.bbl.`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your MWE nearly works for me as is (see note below), but you must run the following commands

```
pdflatex myfile.tex
bibtex myfile.aux
bibtex article.aux
bibtex book.aux
pdflatex myfile.tex
pdflatex myfile.tex
```

Note that the `plain` style gives the error `undefined control sequence \@listctr` which can be fixed by using

```
\bibliographystylebook{apacite}
```

Note that you may have to remove the auxiliary files first.

[image: screenshot]

Following the comments, this process can be streamlined using `TeXworks` as detailed in [Multibib with TeXworks: how to parse second .aux file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66179/multibib-with-texworks-how-to-parse-second-aux-file)

Note that `MiKTeX` is your `TeX` distribution; it is responsible for the executable, package, and class files, but your IDE is responsible for running commands unless you want to use the command line/DOS prompt.

Comment: Also no need to add the file extension in `\bibliographyarticle{publication.bib}` etc.

Comment: @HarishKumar good point

Comment: Thanks, but is there a more streamlined way to make this work within MikTex or is the command-line approach the only way?

Comment: @DanM. this depends. First of all, note that `MiKTeX` is your `TeX` *distribution*; it is responsible for the executable files, but your IDE is responsible for running commands. The `multibib` package provides a lot of flexibility, and you can name your `bibliographies` anything that you like- getting an `IDE` to predict such names will be tricky. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @DanM. see my updated answer

Comment: @DanM. You can try arara for automating the compilation.