# How to split bibliography into cited and non cited references?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I need to include my full bibliography into my report and the references I have used (in **2 separate sections**)

I have my bib file attached to the document and the references are included at the end of the document but I can't find out how to add the full contence of my  bibliography.

**Edit**

The bib file contains 70 records of the reading/research I have done, but I have only cited about half to 3/4 of them. The university wants referenced bibliographies and not referenced bibliographies in separate sections.

I have tried the `\nocite{*}` command but it hasn't worked.

```
\document{begin}
%contense of report 


\section{references}
%References used in paper

\section{bibliography}
%full bibliography

\bibliography{biblyography}%my bib file
\bibliographystyle{cell}
\end{document}
```

hope that is an ok MWE

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: does adding `\nocite{*}` somewhere in the document help?

Comment: it not a duplicate as i need both the references used in the file and the full bib. the \nocite{*} dosen't work as the bib is in a separate file

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about the distinction you make between "references used" in a document and the "full bibliography". Is it like a distinction between "works cited explicitly" and "further works (related to the topic at hand)"?

Comment: @Dan: If it isn't duplicate, please add a minimal working example as described above. Without an MWE we will close this question.

Comment: Your snippet isn't really useful. A MWE can be compiled. So a normal document starts with `\documentclass{...}<some packages><document body>`. However I thunk I can guess what you want. With a normal bibliography style it's very difficult to achieve  your request. But it's very easy with `biblatex`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Yes that is exactly what i mean however this has not worked. i think it is because I have a separate bib file is there another way

Comment: @Dan: Do you want to switch to biblatex?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel If you think that would be better. i have used bibTex to manage my file.

Comment: Using biblatex influences only the LaTeX site. The contents of the bib file don't need to change (normally). I think this will help you [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel yes please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>we have reopened the question.</sub>

Let me try to summarize our comment marathon.

1. Splitting the bibliography in two sections with standard BibTeX is really difficult if you have only one `.bib` file. If you have two `.bib` files you can work with `multibib`. You need one `.bib` file with non referenced entries and one with referenced one. Then you can work with `\nocite{*}`  `multibib` needs a special handling of compilation. A way to simplify these steps is the usage of `arara`: [Multibib with TeXworks: how to parse second .aux file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66179/multibib-with-texworks-how-to-parse-second-aux-file/66183#66183)
2. Using the modern and great package `biblatex` will simplify your life. To switch from a standard style to `biblatex` is described in: [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex). If you switch to `biblatex` you can split your bibliography very simple, what is explained here: [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited) -- It's important to know that `biblatex` uses Biber as backend instead of BibTeX. Although `biblatex` can work with BibTeX you should use Biber to get the "full power" of `biblatex` ;-). The compilation steps are:

   - (pdf)latex
   - biber
   - (pdf)latex
   - (pdf)latex

   Of course these steps can also be simplified by `arara`:

   ```
   % arara: pdflatex
   % arara: biber
   % arara: pdflatex
   % arara: pdflatex
   ```