# Process multiple bibtex files

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

I need your help to find a way to process multiple `bibtex` files in TeXworks for Mac. I have to do this because I am working with `multibib`. At the moment I select `bibtex` and press the green bottom to compile, but the second bibliography is not shown on the output file. Thanks in advance for your support!

To process my document, I have to run `LaTeX` three times and `BibTEX` two times:

- latex mydoc
- bibtex mydoc
- bibtex sec (How I select a different file name?)
- latex mydoc
- latex mydoc

This is a short version of the code I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{sec}{\TeX\ and \LaTeX\ References}

\begin{document}
References to the \TeX book \citeltex{Knuth:1991}
and to Lamport’s \LaTeX\ book, which appears
only in the references\nociteltex{Lamport:1994}.
Finally a cite to a Postscript tutorial
\cite{Adobe:1985}.

\bibliographystylesec{alpha}
\bibliographylsec{lit}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Postscript References}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit}
\end{document}
```

The output should look like this:

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post a minimum working example (MWE) that illustrates the problem you're trying to solve. In particular, please indicate how you load and use the `multibib` package and how and where the file `sec` (short for `sec.tex` or `sec.aux`, I presume) comes into play.

Comment: @HarishKumar Do you know about a tutorial of how to use arara? Thanks

Comment: The arara documentation is a really good tutorial. And this site has some examples if you search :)

Comment: @Mico This is a simple version of what I am trying to do: \usepackage{multibib} 
\newcites{sec}{Additional Sources}

\newpage
\renewcommand{\refname}{References}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{library}

\bibliographystylesec{plainnat}
\bibliographysec{library}

Comment: Instead of adding code in comments, you may please add it to your question body and use `code block` button `{}`.

Comment: @HarishKumar I just finished installing arara and its ready to run with TexWorks. Could you please give me a simple tutorial of how to use it in this particular scenario?

Comment: @HarishKumar Now it should be easier to understand. Thanks

Comment: @HarishKumar My problem is that I still don't know how to use arara syntax in my latex file to process the document. Thanks

Comment: Please check my answer. After correcting the errors in the code, your green button in texworks should work (No need of arara). However, arara is really a cool tool in ones arsenal. Let me know if it doesn't work.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some errors in your code:

1. `\citeltex{Knuth:1991}` is wrong. It should be `\citesec{Knuth:1991}` so that it appears under `\TeX\ and \LaTeX\ References`. Similarly `\nociteltex{Lamport:1994}` should be `\nocitesec{Lamport:1994}`
2. There is a typo in `\bibliographylsec{lit}`. It should be `\bibliographysec{lit}`

With these corrections, the following code works. I have included the `xampl.bib` file that comes bundled with your TeX distribution (as you have provided none).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{sec}{\TeX\ and \LaTeX\ References}

\begin{document}
References to the \TeX book \citesec{book-full}
and to Lamport’s \LaTeX\ book, which appears
only in the references\nocitesec{article-full}.
Finally a cite to a Postscript tutorial
\cite{book-minimal}.

\bibliographystylesec{alpha}
\bibliographysec{xampl}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Postscript References}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`.

[image]

**With `arara`**

Save the following code as `mydoc.tex`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ mydoc, sec ] }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{sec}{\TeX\ and \LaTeX\ References}

\begin{document}
References to the \TeX book \citesec{book-full}
and to Lamport’s \LaTeX\ book, which appears
only in the references\nocitesec{article-full}.
Finally a cite to a Postscript tutorial
\cite{book-minimal}.

\bibliographystylesec{alpha}
\bibliographysec{xampl}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Postscript References}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Then run `arara mydoc` from command line (from the same folder as the mydoc.tex file).

For a more detailed analysis of texworks with `multibib`, refer to this answer by Paulo: [answer by Paulo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66183/11232).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try making these changes and it looks like one step missing in the processing of the file. I compile using pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex. The postscript References are shown perfectly, but the Tex and Latex References are not. Maybe I have to run the the bibtex a second time for the (sec.aux) file. Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance for your continuous support!

Comment: This is working great!!!! Thank you so much Harish!!!! I am so happy!!!!

Comment: @IgnacioSala Glad it worked :-) You are making me happy too (by being happy)