# Bibliography : subdividing into sections

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I would like to subdivide my bibliography into sections to let me distinguish the type of the references. How can I do this?
Actually, I have a `.tex` and a `.bib` example file as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\author{sk001}
\title{My title}


\begin{document}
J'ai inclu un ouvrage général \cite{book1}, et un ouvrage spécialisé \cite{book2}

\bibliography{bibliographie}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\end{document}
```

Ouvrages généraux

```
@book{
book1, 
title="Premier document utilisé",
author="Auteur 1",
year="2013"
}
```

Ouvrages spéciaux

```
@book{
book2,
title="Deuxième document utilisé",
autor="Auteur 2",
year="1998"
}
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: You should have a look at the [`multibib` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/multibib). This posts (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127753/process-multiple-bibtex-files/127770#127770, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146439/multibib-bibliographies-as-subsections/146451#146451) and the documentation, of course, can help you to get into it.

Comment: @Ruben Could you extend your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [`multibib` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/multibib). As the package name suggests it allows you to generate mulitple bibliographies. You can use this to your advantage to create a bibliography for every class of sources that you have, e.g. a bibliography for your general sources and another one for special ones (as you suggested in your question). Of course you can take control on the naming of each bibliography.

This posts

- [Process multiple bibtex files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127753/process-multiple-bibtex-files/127770#127770)
- [Multibib bibliographies as subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146439/multibib-bibliographies-as-subsections/146451#146451)

and the documentation(!) can help you to get into it.

I won't provide an example as the question can be solved with the above hint and elementary package usage, which is explained in the documentation. If you need more help and have specific questions concering the use of the package just ask follow-up-questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can check on `biblatex  refsection` (switching from BibTex to biblatex)

```
    \section{A}
    See \autocite{01}.
    \section{B}
    See \autocite{02}.
   \printbibliography[title={Bib}]
    \appendix
    \newrefsection
    \section{First}
    See \autocite{02}.
    \section{Second}
    Some text \autocite{03}.
    \printbibliography[title={App Bib}]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your posting currently is *not* an answer to the OP's query, as the proposed solution doesn't work with the OP's setup (which uses BibTeX). You should, at a minimum, also explain what the OP needs to do in order to switch from BibTeX to biblatex.

Comment: Thanks Mico - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54940/is-it-possible-to-split-the-bibliography-into-two-different-parts-using-bibtex-t 
This can help when using Bibtex
As Mico has sai you can check on this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex

Comment: I don't think this answers the question as I think the OP was asking about dividing references by *their type* (say, separate sections for books about math and physics), *not* by the chapters of the document. Please change your answer accordingly.